# ensure or ensuring

Tags: gerund-phrases

This sentence extracted from [a book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-JavaScript-Sparkle-Life-Pages/dp/0596521871). I wonder whether 'ensure' has been used correctly here? Or as I guess it should be either 'ensuring' or 'to ensure'?

> What promises do is ensure that callbacks are always handled in the same predictable manner, eliminating some of the nasty surprises and hard-to-find bugs you can get with callbacks alone.

Comment: 'To ensure' here would be fine (compare 'To ensure that callbacks are always handled in the same predictable manner is what promises do), but less formally, 'ensure' is an acceptable deletion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is there a reason you haven't posted that as an answer?

Comment: @John Clifford Two reasons. (1) I'm fairly sure that this is a duplicate, but a brief scan of search results for 'to-deletion + infinitive' has drawn a blank; (2) I estimate it would take me upwards of an hour to find a reference covering to-deletion.

Comment: I figured you'd be able to find references on eliding infinitives fairly easily, but I haven't looked myself so that's fair enough. ^_^

Comment: Here's an in-house reference (though probably not a true duplicate), an answer by [@J Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356436/is-it-correct-to-use-question-words-in-declarative-senteces/356440#356440) from a post essentially asking about Wh-clefts: ...... I want him to trim the hedge. = Wh-Cleft => What I want him to do is (to) trim the hedge. // And [a more comprehensive one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115659/is-this-sentence-correct-what-i-want-to-do-is-read-this-book/115663#115663). //// 'Ensuring' isn't acceptable here in this Wh-cleft structure.